# SQL Server, replace one or more consecutive char

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, char, trim

With SQL Server, is it possible to replace one or more consecutive characters?

For example:

```
select replace(replace(replace('my string   to  split','  ',' '),'   ',' '),'    ',' ')
```

without using a loop?

Comment: If it *just* spaces you want to replace? Or are there other characters?

Comment: *without loop* - what loop where?

Comment: @Luuk if you're going to recommend Regex you should be recommending a CLR function to use said Regex. Otherwise your linked duplicate is useless; SQL Server doesn't support Regex.

Comment: @Larnu, in this case, spaces, but if possible a general solution, should be better

Comment: @Stu, wow! good trick!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No Need for a LOOP**

Here is a little technique Gordon Linoff demonstrated some time ago.

1. Expand
2. Elimnate
3. Restore

You can substitute any `ODD` combination of characters/strings pairs  like `§§` and `||`

**Example**

```
Select replace(replace(replace('my string   to  split',' ','><'),'<>',''),'><',' ')
```

or More Unique strings

```
Select replace(replace(replace('my string   to  split',' ','§§||'),'||§§',''),'§§||',' ')
```

**Results**

```
my string to split
```

Answer (score 0):

use charindex https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_charindex.asp in a looping structure and then use a variable to keep track of the index position.